# Replace value inside brackets using RegEx only where does not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I replace the number inside the brackets for any strings not matching the word "Field".  So the number inside 'SomethingElse' and 'SomethingMore' could be replaced to a new value, but any bracketed value to the right side of the term 'Field' would not be touched.  Note, the word "Field" will always stay the same, so it can be referenced as a magic string in the regex.

```
Field[50].SomethingElse[30]
Field[50].SomethingMore[30]
```

Thanks.
PS. Using JavaScript.

Comment: Will the strings always be in the format you have above? i.e. is the bracket you want to change always at the end of the string?

Comment: No Salgar, could be in the middle of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
str.replace(/(Field\[[^\]]*\]\.[^\[]*)\[(.*)\]/g, "$1["+value+"]");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str.replace(/\b((?!Field\[)\w+)\[\d+\]/g, '$1[' + repl + ']');
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(/(?&lt;!Field)\[([\d]*)\]]/g, '$1['+newnumber+']');`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use "eval" and string manipulation, but if you have to do it that way, you're doing it wrong.

Storing the number "30" to a variable allows it to be manipulated as you require, then just access "SomethingElse" and "SomethingMore" as follows:

```
var n = 30;
// conditional logic;

Field[50].SomethingElse[n]
Field[50].SomethingMore[n]
```

Regards,
Joshua